# A Partition From My External Drive is Recognized by Ubuntu Not in Windows

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, external-hdd

So I have a 1 Tb external hard drive with 3 partitions in NTFS file system. Luckily Ubuntu 2020 is recognizing and displaying files from all the 3 partitions no sweat. However, on Windows 10, only partition number 5 is not recognized and is inaccessible.
[image]

I tried chkdsk command to repair it:

```
chkdsk /f h:
```

But I get this error "Insufficient disk space to fix the Usn Journal.."

[image: Insufficient disk space to fix the Usn Journal]

And Yes I released more space by removing over 50gb of data from partition 5 using Ubuntu live system. Ran the chkdsk command again and i got the same error eventually. I delete even more data to be sure to no avail.

More insights using ubuntu disks (the partition with 495 GB which is highlighted is the one i need to render readable on windows)

[image: ubuntu disks smart data]

This got me wondering how Ubuntu reads external drives differently from windows? To the point that Ubuntu is able to read partitions that windows can't.

So i'm asking **is there a linux based software or a solution to read my external drive within windows and without resorting to a live ubuntu system?**

One more thing i notice after highlighting the Extended partition 4 is that the filesystem is `Ext`. Is it safe to edit it to `NTFS` ?
[image: Extended partition in Ext]

SMART DATA & Self Tests:

https://pastebin.com/U0hbBE2y

Syslog:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ypdt7XHcpp/

Lsusb:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VyZtnSppHs/

I really hope that i'm not asking this question in the wrong stack forum. It just feels that you guys know more about this stuff than those in windows stack forums.

Thank you very much <3

Comment: Are the two partitions unsupported file systems? (I'm not sure what the proper term is, but it's like exFAT, FAT32, etc)

Comment: What partition format can you read, or not read? Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid`. Windows can't read ext2/3/4 Linux partitions. DO NOT install any Windows software to do so, as you will corrupt your Linux installation.

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 All my 3 partitions are NTFS.

Comment: @heynnema I never used my external hard drive in ubuntu until today so all partitions are NTFS

Comment: Have you tried updating all of your windows drivers?

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 Yes did yesterday a fresh install with latest drivers. Though I doubt that to be the problem because it was i wouldn't be able to read partition E and G. Only partition H in my external drive that remains inaccessible. I can see it my computer but cant access it.

Comment: Show me the SMART Data for that drive. You can use Ubuntu's `Disks` application to get that data.

Comment: @heynnema Updated the post with wmic command showing status OK. Oh! is it necessary though using ubuntu?

Comment: The wmic output doesn't show my anything about the condition of the drive. I can't tell you how to get SMART Data in Windows, but in Ubuntu the `Disks` app is probably the easiest.

Comment: @heynnema Ok! Im on it

Comment: @heynnema Updated the post with screenshot of disks highlighting filesystem partition 5 495 gb which is the one windows unable to read. I should mention that my external drive was working fine just a month ago but only yesterday when my windows system broke. I ran an ubuntu live system to copy over some backups before formatting. After formatting I could not read that particular partition on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, however it doesn't show the SMART Data that I'm looking for. Click on the three dot icon to bring up a menu, and select SMART Data & Tests there. In the data window, be aware that it's a scrollable window, so when you screenshot it, make sure to scroll for additional screenshots if required.

Comment: @heynnema Smart data & tests is grayed out for some reason but works on my internal drive. Btw I updated the post with an interesting insights about Extended partition 4. it appears to be Ext not NTFS. I wanted to edit it to NTFS or remove it but im really scared to proceed. What do you think? Thanks you btw for all the help and patience.

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder NEVER modify an extended partition. You'll loose your Ubuntu installation. Sometimes SMART won't work on external USB drives. Install `smartmontools` and `gsmartcontrol` and see if it'll show SMART data.

Comment: @heynnema Oh! About that I don't care about ubuntu installation. All I care about is Partition 5 as it contains all crucial data and backups. so if i edit extended partition 4 to NTFS, all files remain intact?

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder No, never edit an extended partition. An extended partition really isn't a partition, per se, but it's kind of like a container that holds logical partitions 5/6/7 on your MBR formatted disk. Best to install the SMART apps that I call out in my last comment, and see if they'll get SMART data out of the drive. Then boot to Ubuntu, backup your stuff, then delete partition 5 and recreate it, restore the data, and keep your fingers crossed that you don't have a hardware problem.

Comment: @heynnema Ok thanks for the great explanation! I did format partition 6 and 7 and so now im running another chkdsk on windows to see if the problem goes away. Then I will boot into ubuntu install those tools and grab the smart data as requested. Thank you again for your amazing guidance!

Comment: @heynnema I got some tests back: https://pastebin.com/U0hbBE2y And sorry for the delayed response

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder Yes, you have READ ERRORS and 16 potentially bad blocks. This is an external USB disk, correct? Does the enclosure have it's own power supply, or does it draw power from the USB port? Edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` and `grep -i sdc /var/log/syslog*`. Use paste.ubuntu.com if the output is large.

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder Forgot to ask... is the drive a USB3 drive, and/or is it connected to a USB3 port? Edit your question and show me `lsusb`.

Comment: @heynnema updated the question ubuntu pastebin logs except this command 'grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` returning empty output. And yes it is an external hard drive, installed in a usb 3 box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120833/discussion-between-heynnema-and-mrjack-mcfreder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lack of any more meaningful data...

- SMART Data shows that the sdc drive has READ ERRORS and 16 potential bad blocks.
- Syslog does not show NCQ errors, or any other errors related to sdc.

**Note: Backup all NTFS partition data from Windows. Any NTFS partition not accessible from Windows, but is accessible from Ubuntu... then backup all files that way.**

From Windows...

`chkdsk /f h:` # already tried and failed

`chkdsk /r h:` # try to bad block that partition

From Ubuntu...

**Wipe the drive** by laying down a fresh MBR partition table (which is what is there now). I'd normally recommend a GPT partition table.

Create ONE ext4 partition that uses all available unallocated disk space.

Bad block the disk using this procedure...

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

<strike>Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.</strike>

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: wiping out the entire disk would be my last resort giving the tremendous number of files I got on would take a whole day to backup all that data. Yet im still marking it as the answer for now because you found the bad sectors and this command `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` to repair read erros and bad sectors. Thank you for being here for me.

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder OK, try just deleting the bad partition, reiniting as ext4, and then just bad block that partition.

Comment: unfortunately that partition is also the most crucial. I will wait a few days iin case i find something before i attempt your answer.

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder Status please...